# How to ignore unknown values when uploading to bigquery from appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I'm trying to upload data to bigquery in appengine.

here is my code using the  api from this [streaming sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigquery/samples/StreamingSample.java)

```
@Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {

    String projectId = "myprojectId";
    String datasetId = "mydatasetId";
    String tableId = "person";
    System.out.println("Enter JSON to stream to BigQuery: \n" + "Press End-of-stream (CTRL-D) to stop");

    String string = "[\n  {\"Name\": \"test\", \"Age\": 0, \"Weight\": 100.0, \"IsMagic\": false},\n  {\"Name\": \"test\", \"Age\": 1, \"Weight\": 100.0, \"IsMagic\": false},\n  {\"Name\": \"test\", \"Age\": 2, \"Weight\": 100.0, \"IsMagic\": false},\n  {\"Name\": \"test\", \"Age\": 3, \"Weight\": 100.0, \"IsMagic\": false},\n  {\"Name\": \"test\", \"Age\": 0, \"Weight\": 100.0, \"IsMagic\": false}\n]";
    JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(string));

    Iterator<TableDataInsertAllResponse> responses = StreamingSample.run(projectId, datasetId, tableId, jsonReader);

    while (responses.hasNext()) {
        log.info(responses.next());
    }

    jsonReader.close();


}
```

now how can I make big query [ignoreUnknownValues](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load.ignoreUnknownValues)? 
is there any library I can use for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see

```
TableDataInsertAllRequest.setIgnoreUnknownValues()
```

https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/TableDataInsertAllRequest.html#setIgnoreUnknownValues(java.lang.Boolean)